# Powershell - Add to $Error

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Using Powershell, how can I add an entry to the $Error `ArrayCollection` (or possibly, more WHAT should I add to the collection)?

To my undertanding using `Write-Error` will both output the error AND add the entry to the errors collection. But I would just like to have an entry added directly to the collection without outputting at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ErrorAction switch should be able to handle that.

```
write-error "Something bad happened" -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
```